# mongodb check if all subdocuments in array have the same value in one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents, each has a field which is an array of subdocuments, and all subdocuments have a common field 'status'. I want to find all documents that have the same status for all subdocuments.

collection:

```
{
        "name" : "John",
        "wives" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Mary",
                        "status" : "dead"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Anne",
                        "status" : "alive"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "name" : "Bill",
        "wives" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Mary",
                        "status" : "dead"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Anne",
                        "status" : "dead"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "name" : "Mohammed",
        "wives" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Jane",
                        "status" : "dead"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Sarah",
                        "status" : "dying"
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to check if all wives are dead and find only Bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation query to get records of person whose wives are all dead:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$project: {name:1, wives:1, size:{$size:'$wives'}}},
  {$unwind:'$wives'},
  {$match:{'wives.status':'dead'}},
  {$group:{_id:'$_id',name:{$first:'$name'}, wives:{$push: '$wives'},size:{$first:'$size'},count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$project:{_id:1, wives:1, name:1, cmp_value:{$cmp:['$size','$count']}}},
  {$match:{cmp_value:0}}
)
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d401de8b953f35aa92bfb8"), "name" : "Bill", "wives" : [ { "name" : "Mary", "status" : "dead" }, { "name" : "Anne", "status" : "dead" } ], "cmp_value" : 0 }
```

If you need to find records of users who has same status, then you may remove the initial match stage.

Comment: It seems easier to have an extra field to store some kind of flag value there (since I'm interested in only one value of status field). But thanks anyway.

Comment: An extra flag will lead to further updates and finds to keep in synch the flag

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to handle this is always going to be to "match" on the status of "dead" as the opening query, otherwise you are processing items that cannot possibly match, and the logic really quite simply followed with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$allElementsTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "wives.status": "dead" } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$allElementsTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$wives",
                        "as": "wife",
                        "in": { "$eq": [ "$$wife.status", "dead" ] }
                    }
                }               
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}    
])
```

Or the same thing with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```js
db.collection.find({
    "wives.status": "dead",
    "$where": function() {
        return this.wives.length 
            == this.wives.filter(function(el) { 
                el.status == "dead";
            }).length;
    } 
})
```

Both essentially test the "status" value of all elements to make sure they match in the fastest possible way. But the aggregate pipeline with just [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) should be faster. And "less" pipeline stages ( essentially each a pass through the data ) means faster as well.

Of course keeping a property on the document is always fastest, but it would involve logic to set that only where "all elements" are the same property. Which of course would typically mean inspecting the document by loading it from the server prior to each update.